# Finder new window change location

Tags: finder, shortcut

I recently did a clean install of the MacOS Mojave and I am a little bit annoyed by the default folder I get when I press CMD+N in Finder.

How can I change the default folder when I open a new window in Finder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually that is pretty easy, and pretty easy to overlook.

1. Open a new finder window
2. Press <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd>  <kbd>,</kbd>
3. Click on the leftmost icon, "General"

   [image: Finder Preferences]
4. Near the bottom there is a pop-up menu, "New Finder windows show:"
5. Select the location you want from that menu. You will note my Finder windows open with my Home folder, YMMV...